# When using the uigesturerecognizer how can I differentiate between a new pan and a continuation of the first?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

When using the uigesturerecognizer how can I differentiate between a new pan gesture and a continuation of the first?  Is there a unique id associated with each pan that I can use?

Comment: what do you need that for? there is no unique id, but it is also true that none is usually needed...

Comment: Now that I think about it.  I don't think I need it if I use translationInView as opposed to locationInView.

Comment: Both will be notified as seperate gestures..
First will be pan and the second will be just swipe..